# Paint.Net: Center Coordinate of Selected Area?

Tags: paint.net, coordinates

In `Paint.Net` when you select an area using one of select tools, the status bar gives following information:

- **Selection Top Left**
- Bounding Rectangle Size
- Area

In above information I can find **Top-Left** ....  But, I need **Center** Coordinate !

**How can I find `the Center Coordinate of Bounding Rectangle of Selected Area`?**

**PS:** I know I can use `Selection Top Left` and `Bounding Rectangle Size/2` to calculate center, but I want a faster solution because I need to use it in my coding frequently .

Comment: If it's for "coding", why can't you use what you've already indicated?

Comment: @rrirower I can't explain the why here I you don't mind. I'm just looking for alternative solutions.

Comment: Sorry, then, I can't help.

Comment: @rrirower I found it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the proper plugin for my work >> It is [Measure Selection](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/26236-measure-selection-tools-effect/).